# Difference of density ratio in 1D detonation(C-J point) and 1D normal shockwave as p2/p1 goes infinite

Tags: explosions, shock-waves, combustion

1D detonation equations:
$$
\rho_1u_1 = \rho_2u_2
$$
$$
p_1 + \rho_1u_1^2 = p_2+\rho_2u_2^2
$$
$$
c_pT_1 + \frac{1}{2}u_1^2 + Q = c_pT_2 + \frac{1}{2}u_2^2
$$

1D normal shockwave equations:
$$
\rho_1u_1 = \rho_2u_2
$$
$$
p_1 + \rho_1u_1^2 = p_2+\rho_2u_2^2
$$
$$
c_pT_1 + \frac{1}{2}u_1^2 = c_pT_2 + \frac{1}{2}u_2^2
$$

**The difference between 1D detonation wave equation and 1D normal shockwave equation is JUST adding a Q in energy equation.**

Assuming unburned states with subscript 1 and burned with subscript 2.

However, this leads to two different density ratio as $p_2 \gg p_1$.

From upper C-J relation, it is well known that with $p_2 \gg p_1$, the $$\frac{\rho_2}{\rho_1} = (\gamma_2 + 1)/ \gamma_2$$

However in shock physics, what we have is as $M_1$ (mach number before shockwave) goes infinite large, $$\frac{\rho_2}{\rho_1} = (\gamma_2 + 1)/ (\gamma_2-1)$$

However, **$$(\gamma_2 + 1)/ \gamma_2 \ne (\gamma_2 + 1)/ (\gamma_2-1)$$**

**Question:
I know how to derive both of the two results, but just think it is contradictory to my understanding. Say, if I have a very little combustion heat addition, $$ 0 <Q \ll 1$$**
**with very large ratio of $p_2/p_1$ according to C-J point theory, I should get density ratio different than normal shock relation. This is discontinuous in the sense of physics.**

Comment: One of the primary differences between the assumptions used to derive those two sets of equations is the piston, i.e., the thing that rams into the fluid faster than the speed of sound.  In the typical 1D shock derivations, one assumes an infinite piston that is incompressible and moves at a constant speed faster than sound (technically, it could be slightly subsonic in a really cold fluid).  This causes the pile-up of fluid that compresses into a shock...

Comment: In a detonation, the piston is the hot gas released from the explosion, which is not incompressible and thus suffers from mass loading (i.e., eventually the shock piles up enough material that the hot gas pressure can no longer "push" it).  These types of shocks generally have thinner sheaths too.

Answer (score 0):

The major distinction between a one-dimensional CJ detonation wave and a planar shock wave is the post-detonation/shock Mach number. For CJ detonation waves, $M_2$ is always equal to unity (a consequence of the upper CJ point). However, for shock waves, the post-shock Mach number is proportional to $1/M_1$, which is only unity in the limit of acoustic wave propagation. Hence, the physics are not exactly 1 to 1. Additionally, be careful regarding the "simple" step of just adding $Q$ to the detonation wave conservation equations. For instance, what does the enthalpy term $h$ in both equation sets represent? Sensible or chemical enthalpy? For instance, if you have a 1 MJ explosive in a room, does the energy content in the room change after the explosive is detonated? Obviously not, so what does the term $Q$ really represent if we are supposedly saying that both energy equations are a form of conservation?